# React components for On Premise Microsoft PowerApps CRM

Tags: reactjs, powerapps

I'd like to ask whether it is possible to use React for creating components for Microsoft PowerApps. I know it should be possible, but I work with PowerApps On-Premise and I am not sure if it is the same. Some people say that there might be problems with On-Premise, but others say these are not critical, so you just have to spend some extra time.

So, is it ok to use React on On-Premise PowerApps, and if not, which JavaScript framework/library would you recommend?

Big thanks to everyone responding!

Regards, Honza

PS: Sorry for my not-so-good English...

Comment: Your English is good Honza, perfectly understandable. I think that if this Microsoft PowerApps can run modern JS then it will be able to run a react app. You shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Powerapps component framework don’t work on on-premise. For online you can create components using reactjs and pcf